# Send anchor tag value through a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to send anchor tag value through a form?

```
<a href=# id="link">Some Value</a>
```

MY application/ use for this is to be used in a web form, in which the options are listed in a `ul li a` format, rather than a `select option` format.

Is there any workaround to this, **without** using `select option` format? `JS` or `jQuery` solutions preferred.

**edit:** I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971478/ajax-post-echoing-posted-anchor-tag-value), but it involves `ajax`. Is there a pure JS/ jQuery method possible?

Comment: How is the form being posted?  What does an anchor tag have to do with the form post?  Anchor tags don't *have* "values".  Nor are they editable form elements, so it's not really clear what information you're trying to get from the user here in the first place.  Do you have a more complete example?

Comment: He may want to get the `url` user currently visiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may consider to use `<input type="hidden">`.

```
<form>
    <a href=# id="link">Some Value</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="link" value="Some Value"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more detailed please?

Comment: I would do in that way:  `<form><a href=# id="link">Some Value</a><input type="hidden" name="link" value="Some Value"/></form>`

Comment: You should have added this in your answer.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu Possibly. I thought that this tip will be sufficient. Anyway, good suggestion.

Comment: It is better to implement in your answer than providing a big trivial comment.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var current_url = window.location.href;
    var hidden_value = "<input type='hidden' name='url' value='"+current_url+"'>";
    $(YourFormSelector).append(hidden_value);
});
```